# How can i customize ScheduledReboot prompt in wix toolset?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, customization, wix3.6

I've put a scheduled reboot at the end of my installer and it works fine.
The problem is that i made the installer in italian but the scheduled reboot prompt isn't translating even if i use the -cultures it-it command.
Is there some method to customize the message or at least translate it?

```
<ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize" />
```

There's how i build my installer

```
candle.exe MYXML.wxs MYXML.wxs MYXML.wxs
light.exe -ext WixUIExtension -cultures:it-it -out Installer.msi MYWIXOBJ.wixobj MYWIXOBJ.wixobj MYWIXOBJ.wixobj
```

Answer (score 0):

***Conditioning***: I strongly advice you to condition that **`ScheduleReboot`** properly. Here you can read why (**important**): **[Reboot on install, Don't reboot on uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840273/reboot-on-install-dont-reboot-on-uninstall/48842663#48842663)**. Essentially: you do not want to cause an unnecessary reboot in unexpected installation modes (repair, modify, etc...).

You should also be aware that Windows Installer itself will automatically schedule a reboot for files that it is unable to replace during installation. Manually scheduling a reboot should only be done when absolutely necessary.

***Localization***: Let me answer with a question: are you testing on an English Windows machine? If so this is probably an OS dialog and is not embedded in your setup at all.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to translate the message by adding:

```
 <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

to my main .wxs file.
Apparently the -cultures command only affects UI so if you make the reboot prompt part of a UI it will be translated.

Comment: Great, thanks for adding that for others who experience the same problem. Please do check that conditioning issue I mentioned in my answer though. When run in silent mode an MSI with a `ScheduleReboot action` can spontaneously reboot a computer. A very serious problem for knowledge workers who might have dozens of windows open.

Comment: I'm surprised that change worked. The reboot message is one of many that belong to Windows. It would work if something changed the installing users language id to Italian. I wonder at the value of the UserLanguageID property of the install, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372384(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I wonder if Rob decided to exclude those error messages from each WiX MSI by default? Then there is certainly a reason for it, but I am not sure why. If those error messages are missing in the MSI, I would presume the system messages would show up instead? Could the user  have set English as display language, but Italian as system language? Who knows. Not my area.